# How to remote desktop just a single Windows 10 Virtual Desktop, while the client is using the device normally on the other Virtual Desktop?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-access, teamviewer, chrome-remote-desktop

Is it possible to RD only to a single Virtual Desktop (the second VD, Desktop 2), and that RD will just stay there remotely, connecting from other network.

While the client (owner of the device) will still be able to use it's device, interract with it just fine, on the first Virtual Desktop (Desktop 1).

Basically, we're both sharing the PC, while I'm RDing their device, the client will still be able use it.

Is this even technically possible? Is there any RDP apps out there that can do this? Microsoft Remote Desktop? TeamViewer? AnyDesk?

Any other 3rd party RD apps, I'm interested on using or purchasing it, if this kind of scenario is possible.

Comment: “Is it possible to RD only to a single Virtual Desktop (the second VD, Desktop 2), and that RD will just stay there remotely, connecting from other network.” - No; Windows can only have a single Virtual Desktop active at once.

Comment: This feels like a bit of an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  It's hard to propose alternative solutions without knowing *why* you need to do this.  You clearly have a separate computer that you are RDP'ing from. It also doesn't seem like you need to share the screen with the other user, since you mention virtual desktop.  So is it just that you need access to some application on the other user's computer that you can't install on yours?  Is it a shared file that you need to work on?  Some network access that they have and you don't?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 is just for single client usage at a time.
As soon as a second user tries to connect with the same OR other credentials the other one will automatically disconnect. Otherwise terminalservers would be a misconception of microsoft since they are not special anymore.